# Why <array>.[n] type are different from <array>.at(n)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to switch from using `<array>.at()` to `<array>.[]` for consistency. But here is a problem I have run into:

```
const array: string[] = [];

if (array[0]) {
  const item = array[0]; // string
}

if (array.at(0)) {
  const item = array.at(0); // string | undefined
}

if (array[0]) {
  const item = array.at(0); // string | undefined
}
```

Why types are different? I'm missing something? I have read about `at()` method but there not a lot of information about typescript.

`typescript@4.6.4`

Comment: Side note: `at` is not intended to replace all usage of `array[index]`. If a member of my team were switching over to always using it, I'd push back on it. `at` has specific use cases where it's useful; in other cases, it's just a method call for no good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With those `if (array[0])`-style type guards (and particularly since you've now said you have the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` option enabled), arguably the answer is just that TypeScript doesn't narrow types across function calls. After all, in the general case, the function can return a different value on every call (not all functions are *pure*).

You can lock it in with a `const`:

```typescript
// Note: `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` enabled

const array: string[] = [];

if (array[0]) {
    const item = array[0]; 
    //    ^? −−−− string
    console.log(array[0]); // string
}

const item1 = array.at(0);
if (item1) {
    console.log(item1);
    //          ^? −−−− string
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=9#code/PTAEDkHsBcFMC5QAMB2kCqKDGALWWBrWAEwEkVjYAPEgQSy1gGcmlRYUBDAIwBsSAUAKyQUTaKE4AnKZwCeicVICWKAOYBtALqgAvKG0BuIcoBmoABTTZcjQAYtASlABvAaA+gRYicrgBbPUkZeXstQ1B3TxBPUAA9AH4oj28mSH4AOl5INSsQ2wdHCJilVTUBAF8hVN8AgEYg63kMzmgLOyKBM0s-WH865zdY1PTYLJyLXv7O2JjY+cTKgSA)

---

But that raises the interesting question of why *without* the guards are they different (if you *don't* have `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` enabled)?

```typescript
const array: string[] = [];

const i1 = array[0];
//    ^? −−−− string
const i2 = array.at(0);
//    ^? −−−− string | undefined
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngLhtBBLMBzAbQF0YBeGYgbgChrRJZsBGM+JVAgBiJoHpeYgmAD0A-HXDQY2AEytEyFADo4UABScAlHwFCxQA)

I suspect the reason is twofold:

1. Long ago, the TypeScript team took the pragmatic decision that (by default¹) indexed access into an array (like a `string[]`) should return the array's element type (`string`), not the array's element type or `undefined` (`string | undefined`), even though the latter is a more correct interpretation of [property access](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-property-accessors) (which is what indexed access really is) and of the runtime reality that you could indeed get `undefined` from it. Imagine how awkward TypeScript code would be if they hadn't! **Every** array access would involve an `| undefined` that would just end up littering the code with non-null assertions or whatever. So they took the pragmatic approach.
2. The [`at` method](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.at) has much more limited scope than indexed access in general — it's not at all intended to replace indexed access everywhere, and its primary use case is for when indexes are negative. So the types for it reflect the fact that it may return `undefined`, because that *won't* require non-null assertions everywhere — only in places where you use `at` instead of indexed access. So there's no argument for not aligning with the spec and it's more useful for the types to closely align with the specification in this case.

---

¹ Re "by default": You *can* tell TypeScript you want indexed access to include `| undefined` via the [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess). With that option enabled, my example above becomes:

```typescript
// With `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` enabled
const array: string[] = [];

const i1 = array[0];
//    ^? −−−− string | undefined        <== Changed
const i2 = array.at(0);
//    ^? −−−− string | undefined
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=9#code/PTAEHUEsBcAtQAYDsD2BVJBjWBTTBrHAEwEkkicAPYgQU0xwGdGFQckBDAIwBtiAoTCiSNooDgCcJHAJ4AuUKImQkAcwDaAXVABeUFoDc-QcNGhIARl3ips9QAZNRkKFegAegH4TIsZABM1pLSMgB0HNAAFPYAlM5gbl5AA)

Comment: "**Every** array access would involve an `| undefined`" -- If this is the behavior you want, for some reason, you can set the compiler option `noUncheckedIndexedAccess`.

Comment: @Bbrk24 - Thank you for pointing that out! I'd completely forgotten about that option. I never see anyone using it. :-D